# proguard not running in android "ant release"

Tags: android

I read the android documentation for using proguard that says "if we specify proguard.config property it will run proguard "
However I have specified this property, to confirm i checked this in echoproperties but still my files are not obfuscated.
I am not sure if I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Manan

Comment: How are you validating that it is not obfuscated? Did you build as 'release'?

Comment: I think if proguard is run it will generate mapping.txt etc files and also my apk filesize should be somewhat lesser

Comment: What does your proguard.cfg file look like? The output from the build should have some information if it tried to run and encountered a problem with the config file.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on android.developer.com about proguard is not complete. You may also need to set

```
android:debuggable="false"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file

I found that I needed to do this in addition to specifying the config file in project.properties

Then after running ant release it will run proguard.  The manual only says that android debug will not generate proguard, but it does not make it clear that you cannot even have debuggable set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link.it will help you about Proguard and how to build [Proguard]

[ANT build for Android Proguard obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629444/ant-build-for-android-proguard-obfuscation)

Comment: While that does cover some details, it is not really up to date with the latest tools. The current SDK has ProGuard support built into the auto generated ANT build files (using the android command). http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using Eclipse.
Simply add the following line to your *project.propeties* file:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

here are the steps

1. Enable the proguard.config in project.properties file

   [image]
2. create proguard-project.txt file, it should be shown as below

   [image]
3. run "ant release"